# Disable Mail in emacs 23

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, emacs23

I am wondering if its possible to disable mail in emacs 23.  Basically, I occasionally press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> and it annoys me that it will create a Mail folder in my home directory. (I also want to remap this to 'execute-extended command).

I have tried

```
(global-unset-key "\C-x m")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") 'execute-extended-command)
```

but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Ahh, I the space in "\C-x m" makes it not work.  However, if I use "\C-xm", it unsets it like I expect.  And, for some reason I didn't see my typo on the second line of code:  It should be (kbd "C-x m").  This also fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will set the binding of <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to the `execute-extended-command` function:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-xm" 'execute-extended-command)
```

or

```
(global-set-key [?\C-x ?m] 'execute-extended-command)
```

or

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x m") 'execute-extended-command)
```